# Armazenando um vetor de caracteres dentro de uma memoria heap

Tags: c, heap

Gostaria de saber como ordeno um conjunto de caracteres em um vetor, e o armazeno dentro na memoria heap.

Comment: O que você já tentou? Mostre o código que já escreveu e reformule a pergunta com a dúvida/problema específico que você está enfrentando.

Answer (score 1):

Um vetor (array dinâmico) *sempre* estará no heap. Você pode, com as funções multiplataforma do std C, usar [`malloc, calloc & família`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) (informações no link) para alocar dinamicamente memória. Para fazer sorting do vetor, você pode usar um dos [vários algoritmos de sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) , onde cada um pode ter um caso específico (melhor e pior) e você deve decidir qual te atende melhor (grande quantia de informação / menos quantia de informação). É importante notar que durante o processo de sorting, muitas vezes vale mais à pena alocar outro bloco de memória (do tamanho do vetor original, obviamente) e progressivamente ir adicionando os dados ordenados. Assim, você deleta o vetor antigo (libera espaço), tem o vetor ordenado (espaço previamente alocado) e economiza um bom trabalho.

Em relação ao sort, um dos melhores algoritmos é o [Quicksort](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#C.2FC.2B.2B), embora (como já dito) existam ourtos eficientes[<sup>1</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Efficient_sorts).